# is it possible to create a website with wordpress with these requirements without coading?

Tags: themes

is it possible to create a website with wordpress with these requirements without coading? if possible which would be the best theme?Thank you.
Website Requirements

1.Need to be an eCommerce marketplace 
2.Need to accept paypal, credit card payments etc. 
3.Manage inventory and products
4.Be able to cross sell on eBay, Amazon, Facebook, Instagram
5.Show shipping estimates to local and overseas customers. 
6.Should be able to easily manage products from suppliers, thus staying upto date with supplier stock on hand. 
7.Be able to run promotions and sales on  products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from cross selling, all requirements are covered by a standard installation of WordPress with the WooCommerce plugin. I've seen (but never used) a free extension for Facebook. For the other platforms you need to search for extensions, maybe payed extensions on woocommerce store or codecanyon.

I can not tell you what would be the best theme, but maybe the Hello Theme by Elementor and the Plugin Elementor is a good fit to customize everythin without coding.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i handle this "Should be able to easily manage products from suppliers, thus staying upto date with supplier stock on hand."?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't go into more detail on this in my answer. Often suppliers have an API to maintain the inventory. Since a requirement is 'no coding', you can create an account for the supplier if no plugin is offered by the supplier. For example, with ATUM Inventory Management (https://wordpress.org/plugins/atum-stock-manager-for-woocommerce/) every supplier can maintain his inventory himself.